# Logins and Users migration to different SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

How to transfer 120 logins to another server without script?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not programming question

Comment: why don't you just detatch the database, move the files to new server and attache the database to the new server.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a script?

Answer (score 0):

There are four ways to transfer it to another SQL server

1. The contained databases
2. The SSIS Transfer Login Task
3. The Database Migration Wizard
4. The Microsoft scripts

which one you want to use it depends. Check [this](http://www.sqlshack.com/migrate-logins-database-different-server/) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Just for information. We have a script that dumps all logins and permissions from SQL-server:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @message NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- GENERATE LOGINS CREATE SCRIPT


USE [master]

-- creating accessory procedure

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM    sys.objects WHERE   object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'sp_hexadecimal') AND type IN ( N'P', N'PC' )) 
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_hexadecimal]
EXEC('
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_hexadecimal]
    @binvalue varbinary(256),
    @hexvalue varchar (514) OUTPUT
AS
DECLARE @charvalue varchar (514)
DECLARE @i int
DECLARE @length int
DECLARE @hexstring char(16)
SELECT @charvalue = ''0x''
SELECT @i = 1
SELECT @length = DATALENGTH (@binvalue)
SELECT @hexstring = ''0123456789ABCDEF''
WHILE (@i <= @length)
BEGIN
  DECLARE @tempint int
  DECLARE @firstint int
  DECLARE @secondint int
  SELECT @tempint = CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(@binvalue,@i,1))
  SELECT @firstint = FLOOR(@tempint/16)
  SELECT @secondint = @tempint - (@firstint*16)
  SELECT @charvalue = @charvalue +
    SUBSTRING(@hexstring, @firstint+1, 1) +
    SUBSTRING(@hexstring, @secondint+1, 1)
  SELECT @i = @i + 1
END

SELECT @hexvalue = @charvalue')

SET @message = '-- CREATE LOGINS' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(13) +'USE [master]' + CHAR(13)

DECLARE @name sysname
DECLARE @type varchar (1)
DECLARE @hasaccess int
DECLARE @denylogin int
DECLARE @is_disabled int
DECLARE @PWD_varbinary  varbinary (256)
DECLARE @PWD_string  varchar (514)
DECLARE @SID_varbinary varbinary (85)
DECLARE @SID_string varchar (514)
DECLARE @tmpstr  NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @is_policy_checked varchar (3)
DECLARE @is_expiration_checked varchar (3)

DECLARE @defaultdb sysname

DECLARE login_curs CURSOR FOR
      SELECT p.sid, p.name, p.type, p.is_disabled, p.default_database_name, l.hasaccess, l.denylogin FROM 
sys.server_principals p LEFT JOIN sys.syslogins l
      ON ( l.name = p.name ) WHERE p.type IN ( 'S', 'G', 'U' ) AND p.name <> 'sa'

OPEN login_curs

FETCH NEXT FROM login_curs INTO @SID_varbinary, @name, @type, @is_disabled, @defaultdb, @hasaccess, @denylogin
IF (@@fetch_status = -1)
BEGIN
  PRINT 'No login(s) found.'
  CLOSE login_curs
  DEALLOCATE login_curs
END

WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
BEGIN
  IF (@@fetch_status <> -2)
  BEGIN

    IF (@type IN ( 'G', 'U'))
    BEGIN -- NT authenticated account/group

      SET @tmpstr = 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT loginname FROM master.dbo.syslogins WHERE name = ''' + @name + ''' AND dbname = ''' + @defaultdb + ''')' + CHAR(13) +
                    'BEGIN TRY' + CHAR(13) +
                    '   CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME( @name ) + ' FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = [' + @defaultdb + ']'

    END
    ELSE BEGIN -- SQL Server authentication
        -- obtain password and sid
            SET @PWD_varbinary = CAST( LOGINPROPERTY( @name, 'PasswordHash' ) AS varbinary (256) )
        EXEC sp_hexadecimal @PWD_varbinary, @PWD_string OUT
        EXEC sp_hexadecimal @SID_varbinary,@SID_string OUT

        -- obtain password policy state
        SELECT @is_policy_checked = CASE is_policy_checked WHEN 1 THEN 'ON' WHEN 0 THEN 'OFF' ELSE NULL END FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE name = @name
        SELECT @is_expiration_checked = CASE is_expiration_checked WHEN 1 THEN 'ON' WHEN 0 THEN 'OFF' ELSE NULL END FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE name = @name

            SET @tmpstr = 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT loginname FROM master.dbo.syslogins WHERE name = ''' + @name + ''' AND dbname = ''' + @defaultdb + ''')' + CHAR(13) +
                    'BEGIN TRY' + CHAR(13) +
                    '   CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME( @name ) + ' WITH PASSWORD = ' + @PWD_string + ' HASHED, SID = ' + @SID_string + ', DEFAULT_DATABASE = [' + @defaultdb + ']'

        IF ( @is_policy_checked IS NOT NULL )
        BEGIN
          SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + ', CHECK_POLICY = ' + @is_policy_checked
        END
        IF ( @is_expiration_checked IS NOT NULL )
        BEGIN
          SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + ', CHECK_EXPIRATION = ' + @is_expiration_checked
        END
    END
    IF (@denylogin = 1)
    BEGIN -- login is denied access
      SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + '; DENY CONNECT SQL TO ' + QUOTENAME( @name )
    END
    ELSE IF (@hasaccess = 0)
    BEGIN -- login exists but does not have access
      SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + '; REVOKE CONNECT SQL TO ' + QUOTENAME( @name )
    END
    IF (@is_disabled = 1)
    BEGIN -- login is disabled
      SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + '; ALTER LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME( @name ) + ' DISABLE'
    END

    SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + CHAR(13) + 'END TRY' + CHAR(13) + 'BEGIN CATCH' + CHAR(13) + 'END CATCH'

    SET @message = @message + CHAR(13) + @tmpstr

  END

  FETCH NEXT FROM login_curs INTO @SID_varbinary, @name, @type, @is_disabled, @defaultdb, @hasaccess, @denylogin
   END
CLOSE login_curs
DEALLOCATE login_curs

--removing accessory procedure

DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_hexadecimal]


-- GENERATE SERVER PERMISSIONS
USE [master]

DECLARE @ServerPrincipal SYSNAME
DECLARE @PrincipalType SYSNAME 
DECLARE @PermissionName SYSNAME
DECLARE @StateDesc SYSNAME

SET @message = @message + CHAR(13) + CHAR(13) + '-- CREATE SERVER PERMISSIONS' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(13) +'USE [master]' + CHAR(13)

DECLARE server_permissions_curs CURSOR FOR
SELECT
  [srvprin].[name] [server_principal], 
  [srvprin].[type_desc] [principal_type], 
  [srvperm].[permission_name], 
  [srvperm].[state_desc]  
FROM [sys].[server_permissions] srvperm 
  INNER JOIN [sys].[server_principals] srvprin 
    ON [srvperm].[grantee_principal_id] = [srvprin].[principal_id] 
WHERE [srvprin].[type] IN ('S', 'U', 'G') AND [srvprin].name NOT IN ('sa', 'dbo', 'information_schema', 'sys')
ORDER BY [server_principal], [permission_name]; 

OPEN server_permissions_curs

FETCH NEXT FROM server_permissions_curs INTO @ServerPrincipal, @PrincipalType, @PermissionName, @StateDesc 

WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
BEGIN

    SET @message = @message + CHAR(13) + 'BEGIN TRY' + CHAR(13) + 
                    @StateDesc + N' ' + @PermissionName + N' TO ' + QUOTENAME(@ServerPrincipal) + 
                    + CHAR(13) + 'END TRY' + CHAR(13) + 'BEGIN CATCH' + CHAR(13) + 'END CATCH'

    FETCH NEXT FROM server_permissions_curs INTO @ServerPrincipal, @PrincipalType, @PermissionName, @StateDesc 
END
CLOSE server_permissions_curs
DEALLOCATE server_permissions_curs

--GENERATE USERS AND PERMISSION SCRIPT FOR EVERY DATABASE

SET @message = @message + CHAR(13) + CHAR(13) + N'--ENUMERATE DATABASES'

DECLARE @databases TABLE (
    DatabaseName SYSNAME,
    DatabaseSize INT,
    Remarks SYSNAME NULL
)

INSERT INTO
@databases EXEC sp_databases

DECLARE @DatabaseName SYSNAME


DECLARE database_curs CURSOR FOR
SELECT DatabaseName FROM @databases WHERE DatabaseName IN (N'${DatabaseName}')

OPEN database_curs

FETCH NEXT FROM database_curs INTO @DatabaseName
WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
BEGIN

    SET @tmpStr = 

    N'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName) + '

    DECLARE @tmpstr  NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @messageOut = CHAR(13) + CHAR(13) + ''USE ' + QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName) + ''' + CHAR(13)

    -- GENERATE USERS SCRIPT 

    SET @messageOut = @messageOut + CHAR(13) + ''-- CREATE USERS '' + CHAR(13)

    DECLARE @users TABLE (
    UserName SYSNAME Null,  
    RoleName SYSNAME Null,  
    LoginName SYSNAME Null, 
    DefDBName SYSNAME Null, 
    DefSchemaName SYSNAME Null, 
    UserID INT Null,    
    [SID] varbinary(85) Null
    )

    INSERT INTO
    @users   EXEC sp_helpuser

    DECLARE @UserName SYSNAME
    DECLARE @LoginName SYSNAME 
    DECLARE @DefSchemaName SYSNAME

    DECLARE user_curs CURSOR FOR
    SELECT UserName, LoginName, DefSchemaName FROM @users

    OPEN user_curs

    FETCH NEXT FROM user_curs INTO @UserName, @LoginName, @DefSchemaName
    WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
    BEGIN

        SET @messageOut = @messageOut + CHAR(13) + 
                        ''IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N''''''+ @UserName +'''''')''
                        + CHAR(13) + ''BEGIN TRY'' + CHAR(13) + 
                        ''  CREATE USER '' + QUOTENAME(@UserName)

        IF (@LoginName IS NOT NULL)
            SET @messageOut = @messageOut + '' FOR LOGIN '' + QUOTENAME(@LoginName)
        ELSE
            SET @messageOut = @messageOut + '' WITHOUT LOGIN''  

        IF (@DefSchemaName IS NOT NULL)
            SET @messageOut = @messageOut + '' WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = ''  + QUOTENAME(@DefSchemaName)

        SET @messageOut = @messageOut + CHAR(13) + ''END TRY'' + CHAR(13) + ''BEGIN CATCH'' + CHAR(13) + ''END CATCH''

        FETCH NEXT FROM user_curs INTO @UserName, @LoginName, @DefSchemaName
    END
    CLOSE user_curs
    DEALLOCATE user_curs

    -- GENERATE ROLES

    SET @messageOut = @messageOut + CHAR(13) + CHAR(13) + ''-- CREATE ROLES '' + CHAR(13)

    SELECT @messageOut = @messageOut + CHAR(13) + ''BEGIN TRY'' + CHAR(13) + 
                        N''EXEC sp_addrolemember N''''''+ rp.name +'''''', N''''''+ mp.name +''''''''
                        + CHAR(13) + ''END TRY'' + CHAR(13) + ''BEGIN CATCH'' + CHAR(13) + ''END CATCH''
    FROM sys.database_role_members drm
    join sys.database_principals rp ON (drm.role_principal_id = rp.principal_id)
    join sys.database_principals mp ON (drm.member_principal_id = mp.principal_id)
    WHERE mp.name NOT IN (N''dbo'')


    -- GENERATE PERMISSIONS

    SET @messageOut = @messageOut + CHAR(13) + CHAR(13) + ''-- CREATE PERMISSIONS '' + CHAR(13)

    SELECT @messageOut = @messageOut + CHAR(13) + ''BEGIN TRY'' + CHAR(13) + 
                        ''  GRANT '' + dp.permission_name collate latin1_general_cs_as +
                        '' ON '' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + ''.'' + QUOTENAME(o.name) + '' TO '' + QUOTENAME(dpr.name)  +
                        + CHAR(13) + ''END TRY'' + CHAR(13) + ''BEGIN CATCH'' + CHAR(13) + ''END CATCH''
    FROM sys.database_permissions AS dp
    INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON dp.major_id=o.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
    INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS dpr ON dp.grantee_principal_id=dpr.principal_id
    WHERE dpr.name NOT IN (''public'',''guest'')'

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @tmpStr, N'@messageOut NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT', @messageOut = @tmpstr OUTPUT

    SET @message = @message + @tmpStr

    FETCH NEXT FROM database_curs INTO @DatabaseName
END
CLOSE database_curs
DEALLOCATE database_curs

SELECT @message
```

Comment: Source for the first chunk of this: [Microsoft KB918992](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/918992). There's a description there of what it does and how to use it.